# Simplification of multiple factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I was confused on how I am wrong on this question. When I checked by putting in values for $x$, I was correct, and this cannot be factored further.

[image]

Ignore the other submissions other than the last one (my final answer). Is there something I'm doing wrong, or any pointers to go on the correct path? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

I'm in agreement with you.  This appears to be a mistake. $2x^2+x+3$ doesn't factor...

Comment: Yeah i emailed my professor, will see what he says,

Comment: Sounds good.   Let me know what he says,  if you don't mind.

Comment: Definitely! I'll remind him this lecture in 30min to check his email.

Comment: He still didnt respond :/

Answer (score 2):

Your third answer is totally correct. You can also use polynomial division to show it is $$2x+\frac{48}{x+5}-9$$
perhaps this is the form they require. It could also be that the page you're using is ultra-picky about formatting and you formatted it differently to the given answer

Comment: Yeah i emailed my professor about this, will see what he says about this.